# Requerying an object causes entire form to requery

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got a report embedded into a form that I want to requery/refresh after the user clicks a button. I've tried multiple different approaches, but no matter what I do, instead of requerying/refreshing just the specified object, the entire form requerys/refreshes, which causes some issues. Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
Me.objectname.requery

DoCmd.Requery "objectname"

objectname.requery
```

I'm fairly certain I've done this before and not had this issue, but I feel like I could be missing something obvious.

It might also be worth mentioning that I have code in the OnOpen event that resets the form to all its original values, maybe thats whats causing the issue?

If anyone knows why this is happening, please let me know! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual syntax for requerying a subform is:

```
Me.ObjectName.Form.Requery 'For a form
```

Or:

```
Me.ObjectName.Report.Requery 'For a report
```

Comment: Aaahh I knew I was missing something silly. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Well, the many, many ways to requery/refresh things in VBA makes it difficult, it's a concept I struggled with too in my early days :)